# Browsers based Live video chat with no flash

Tags: javascript, html, video, ffmpeg, webrtc

On server side I need to convert the uploded incoming webRTC streming into sequence of binary image data
with ffmpeg for example or other tool

Dose anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve "upload" of live video in a browser without Flash is to use WebRTC, hence support for non-WebRTC browsers is impossible.

Receiving video in the browser can be done without Flash using MPEG-DASH and also by way of HLS.js (https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js/tree/master).

Not sure there's anything off-the-shelf. You'll need to do some coding on your own.